# Datamapper, defining your own object methods, how?

Tags: ruby, database, datamapper

So lets say I have a class like below

```
class List
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial  
  property :username, String

  def self.my_username
    return self[:username]
  end
end

list=List.create(:username=>,'jim')
list.my_username
```

When I run this it tells me that the method cannot be found, and on more investigation that you can only define class methods(not object methods) and that class methods don't have access to objects data.

Is there any way to have these methods included as object methods and get access to object data? I'm using Ruby 1.8.6 and the latest version of datamapper.

Comment: Why define it like ClassMethod if you use it only like InstanceMethod ?

Answer (score 7):

Avoid all self and it become InstanceMethod :

```
class List
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial  
  property :username, String

  def my_username
    return self[:username]
  end
end

list=List.create(:username=>'jim')
list.my_username
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be (:username => 'jim') without the comma ?

Answer (score 4):

You can think of the class scope as the `Model` (a table in an RDBMS) and of the instance scope as the `Resource` (a row in an RDBMS). Now if you define class methods (like you did with `self.my_username`) you are operating on the `Model` (aka the table, aka *all* rows). If you define instance methods, these will be available to a `Resource`(aka *one* row).

Typical usecases for class methods are to build up (chains of) query/ies. These will basically work to the same effect as Active Record's 2.x `named_scope`. You can call a chain of class methods and have it not execute a single query, as long as you don't explicitly access the data the query is supposed to provide. `DataMapper` will keep on constructing and modifying query objects till the very moment you actually need to access the data. This only works if every class method in the chain returns an instance of `DataMapper::Collection` which is typically achieved by returning the result of calls to `all` (or combining these with set operators like `+`, `-`, `&` and `|`.